# Groupby column and find min and max of each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset,

```
        Day    Element  Data_Value
6786    01-01   TMAX    112
9333    01-01   TMAX    101
9330    01-01   TMIN    60
11049   01-01   TMIN    0
6834    01-01   TMIN    25
11862   01-01   TMAX    113
1781    01-01   TMAX    115
11042   01-01   TMAX    105
1110    01-01   TMAX    111
651     01-01   TMIN    44
11350   01-01   TMIN    83
1798    01-02   TMAX    70
4975    01-02   TMAX    79
12774   01-02   TMIN    0
3977    01-02   TMIN    60
2485    01-02   TMAX    73
4888    01-02   TMIN    31
11836   01-02   TMIN    26
11368   01-02   TMAX    71
2483    01-02   TMIN    26
```

I want to group by the Day and then find the overall min of TMIN an the max of TMAX and put these in to a data frame, so I get an output like...

```
Day    DayMin    DayMax
01-01  0         115
01-02  0         79
```

I know I need to do,

```
df.groupby(by='Day')
```

but I am a stuck with the next step - should create columns to store the TMAX and TMIN values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `assign` + `abs`, followed by `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df = (df.assign(Data_Value=df['Data_Value'].abs())
       .groupby(['Day'])['Data_Value'].agg([('Min' , 'min'), ('Max', 'max')])
       .add_prefix('Day'))

df 
       DayMin  DayMax
Day                  
01-01       0     115
01-02       0      79
```

Comment: So idiot me. I totally forgot we can pass list to agg :). Its ohk I got column names atleast as a defence

Comment: @Bharathshetty Sorry, I didn't see your answer when editing mine. I would believe you need to take the absolute condition into account as well.

Comment: You are making an assumption that TMIN will not have value greater than TMAX?

Comment: @Zero I didn't read anything into the data. Actually, I might've misread the question.

Comment: It is also possible that TMIN is negative, can I avoid using abs() here?

Comment: @TheCat Welp, you did say you wanted the absolute... hence the use of `abs`. If you don't want it, just remove the assign call. Everything else remains.

Comment: Oh yeh, my bad, I sort of meant rather the overall min/max rather than any kind of average.

Comment: @TheCat No problem. The rest should still be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
In [5265]: def maxmin(x):
      ...:     mx = x[x.Element == 'TMAX'].Data_Value.max()
      ...:     mn = x[x.Element == 'TMIN'].Data_Value.min()
      ...:     return pd.Series({'DayMin': mn, 'DayMax': mx})
      ...:

In [5266]: df.groupby('Day').apply(maxmin)
Out[5266]:
       DayMax  DayMin
Day
01-01     115       0
01-02      79       0
```

Also,

```
In [5268]: df.groupby('Day').apply(maxmin).reset_index()
Out[5268]:
     Day  DayMax  DayMin
0  01-01     115       0
1  01-02      79       0
```

Or, use `query` instead of `x[x.Element == 'TMAX']` as `x.query("Element == 'TMAX'")`

Answer (score 1):

Create duplicate columns and find min and max using agg i.e

```
ndf = df.assign(DayMin = df['Data_Value'].abs(),DayMax=df['Data_Value'].abs()).groupby('Day')\
     .agg({'DayMin':'min','DayMax':'max'})
```

```
     DayMax  DayMin
Day                  
01-01     115       0
01-02      79       0
```

Incase you want both TMIN and TMAX then `groupby(['Day','Element'])`