# How do I create a new DataFrame filled with minimum and maximum values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpI6PlO8ox2vKfM4aGmEUexCPPWa59S_

How do I create a new DataFrame where the first column is the unique neighbourhood names and the next two columns are filled with the minimum and maximum price for each neighbourhood?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groupby column and find min and max of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501703/groupby-column-and-find-min-and-max-of-each-group)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still stuck with how I can use that solution for my data?

Comment: `df.groupby('neighborhood')['price'].agg(['max','min'])`.

Comment: If I use the following line...df.groupby('neighbourhood_hosts')['minPrice'].agg(['min', 'max']) I do not get the correct value for the maxPrice column

Comment: This hasn't helped me enough but thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group by the hosts and get max and min value like below:

```
>>> data = pd.read_csv('dumbbell_data.csv')
>>> pd.DataFrame([[value.maxPrice.max(), value.minPrice.min(), key] for key, value in data.groupby('neighbourhood_hosts')], columns=data.columns)
   maxPrice  minPrice neighbourhood_hosts
0        45        45          Bloomsbury
1       247       117           Canonbury
2       112        72             Chelsea
3       160        29        LB of Barnet
4        80        72       LB of Hackney
5       321        58     Shepherd's Bush
6        72        55          Shoreditch
7       115        72             Wapping
8       120        58           Wimbledon
```

A more Pythonic way is to use `agg` function:

```
>>> data.sort_values(by='neighbourhood_hosts').groupby('neighbourhood_hosts').agg({'maxPrice': max, 'minPrice':min})
                     maxPrice  minPrice
neighbourhood_hosts                    
Bloomsbury                 45        45
Canonbury                 247       117
Chelsea                   112        72
LB of Barnet              160        29
LB of Hackney              80        72
Shepherd's Bush           321        58
Shoreditch                 72        55
Wapping                   115        72
Wimbledon                 120        58
```